# Is P the same as P-Complete?

Tags: theory, complexity-theory

Is P the same as P-Complete in Complexity Theory?
I need to know whether the two classes are identical. Because I have a Karp reduction between any two but can't find it on the internet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Any problem in P can be polynomial-time reduced (both many-one and
>   Turing) to **almost** any other problem in P.
>
> The sole reason to say "**almost**" is because there is one problem (and
>   its complement) which no other problems can be many-one reduced to
>   (although they can be Turing reduced to): the problem that accepts
>   everything (and the one that rejects everything).

Source: [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polynomial_time_reduction)

Comment: Typically, when talking about P-completeness, a weaker form of reduction than polynomial time reducibility is used for the reason you listed.  Usually, something like logspace or AC^0 reducibility is used.